# Invisible button not responsive to being tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to put an invisible button over an imageview because the imageview is too small to be responsive to a tap gesture recognizer. I can't just make the image bigger bc it looks bad. Here's the code for the imageview for increasing the quantity:

```
private func configureIncreaseQuantityImageView() {
    increaseQuantityImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    increaseQuantityImageView.image = UIImage(named: "arr_up")
    //increaseQuantityImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //increaseQuantityImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleIncreaseQuantityTapped)))
    contentView.addSubview(increaseQuantityImageView)
    increaseQuantityImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    increaseQuantityImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalDivider.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    increaseQuantityImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalDivider.rightAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    increaseQuantityImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12).isActive = true
    increaseQuantityImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8).isActive = true
}
```

Here's the code for the invisible button that doesn't respond to touch:

```
private func configureInvisibleIncreaseQuantityButton() {
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.backgroundColor = .clear
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleIncreaseQuantityTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    contentView.addSubview(invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton)
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalDivider.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalDivider.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    invisibleIncreaseQuantityButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
}
```

Here's the function that doesn't get called upon touching the invisible button. I did something very similar for the decrease quantity button so no need to show that code.

```
@objc private func handleIncreaseQuantityTapped() {
    self.quantity += 1
    quantityValueLabel.text = "\(self.quantity)"
    self.menuItem?.quantity = self.quantity
    guard let item = self.menuItem else { return }
    delegate?.updateMenuItem(item)
}
```

Comment: Invisible views don't register touches.

Comment: If the image is too small to register taps, then you may well have an accessibility/usability issue anyway.  Maybe you could use a `UIButton` but change the `contentInsets` so that the button is larger than the image?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you don't need a button to do this. You can accomplish the same thing by simply using a UIView that is layered over the object.

But there are a few considerations when doing this programmatically, mainly, that you don't actually visually see where the UI object is located due to it being all handled in code instead of a storyboard.

My suggestions:
1) User interaction might not be enabled on your view
increaseQuantityImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

2) The view you are trying to interact with is buried behind another view in the subview hierarchy

The `.addSubview()` function could be placing the object you want to be touched *under* the object that it is supposed to be covering.

Here is a nifty little snippet that I use a lot to find a subview really quickly:

This function returns all the subviews contained in a provided view as an array.

```
private func getSubviewsOf<T : UIView>(view:UIView) -> [T] {
        var subviews = [T]()

        for subview in view.subviews {
            subviews += getSubviewsOf(view: subview) as [T]

            if let subview = subview as? T {
                subviews.append(subview)
            }
        }
        return subviews
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
// First, let's get an ID on the object you are trying to find
`invisibleDecreaseQuantityButton.restorationIdentifier = "targetView"`

// Then, also set a restoration ID on the view that this targetView is supposed to be on top of
increaseQuantityImageView.restorationIdentifier = "coveredView"

// Now, get all of the subviews of the main view
let subviews = self.getSubViewsOf(view: self.view)

var targetViewIndex = 0
var coveredViewIndex = 0
// Figure out which view is the correct one
for (index, view) in subviews.enumerated() {

    // When we find the target view
    if view.restorationIdentifier == "targetView" {
        // Let's print it so we know where it resides
        print("targetView's index: \(index)")
        targetViewIndex = index
    }

    if view.restorationIdentifier == "coveredView"{
        // print this one too
        print("coveredView's index: \(index)")
        coveredViewIndex = index
    }
}
```

This portion is really just meant to help you debug programmatically. If you want to get a more visual debugging method into your app, I would highly recommend [FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX). With this framework, you can visually tap each element and get it's variable name, and visually see a graph with the placement of your entire view hierarchy in the view controller.

Remember that in the view hierarchy, the view with the *lower* index in the array of subviews means it is closer to the top of the view. So:

```
if targetIndex > coveredViewIndex {
    // push the coveredView behind the targetView
    self.view.insertSubview(targetView, at: coveredViewIndex)
}
```

More on hierarchies here in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html)

Lmk if I can help you debug further. Here's a little screencap of FLEX that I just made, it's a great tool:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4.2

You can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your `imageView`'s superview, and set a range that contain the `imageView`'s location.

For example:

```
let superviewOfImageView = UIView()
let imageView = UIImageView()

func setupTapGesture() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
    superviewOfImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func didTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // user's finger tap at superview's location.
    let point = gesture.location(in: superviewOfImageView)

    // set the range you want.
    let width = superviewOfImageView.frame.width/4 
    let height = superviewOfImageView.frame.height/4
    let boundaryOfImageView = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    // if in the range you set, do what ever you want.
    if boundaryOfImageView.contains(point) {
        // do something here.
    }
}
```

Good luck my friend!